# WP_Query posts pagination

Tags: wordpress

Guys! I'm trying to paginate posts in 5 posts per page. but I'm using WP_Query. Can you point me somewhere where I can get information to accomplish it. thanks.

```
    <?php $preNewsPosts = new WP_Query();
    $preNewsPosts->query('category_name=news&posts_per_page=30');
    while($preNewsPosts->have_posts()): $preNewsPosts->the_post();
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>
    <hr style="width: 95%; border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; " />
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one article](http://tclayson.com/2012/03/28/custom-wp_query-and-loop-with-pagination-without-plugins/) explaining in detail how to accomplish pagination with custom WP_Query.

Basically you modify your code, so that it looks something like this:

```
<?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $preNewsPosts = new WP_Query();
    $preNewsPosts->query('category_name=news&posts_per_page=30&paged=' . $paged);
    while($preNewsPosts->have_posts()): $preNewsPosts->the_post();
    ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?></a>
      <hr style="width: 95%; border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; " />
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>

<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $preNewsPosts->max_num_pages) ?></div>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;', $preNewsPosts->max_num_pages) ?></div>
</div>
```